# Django Class-based View Create then Redirect to Detail View Error

Tags: python, django, url, web-applications

I have an app called workspace,

somewhere in my form_valid definition in my

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    obj = form.instance
    obj.owner = self.request.user
    obj.sort_order = Project.default_sort_order()
    obj.workspace = get_object_or_404(Workspace, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    context = self.get_context_data()
    attribute_form = context['attribute_formset']
    if attribute_form.is_valid():
        self.object = form.save()
        for aform in attribute_form:
            aform.instance.owner = self.request.user
            attribute = aform.save()
            self.object.attributes.add(attribute)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(self.get_success_url()))
    else:
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

and my definition for the get_success_url:

```
def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('workspace_project', kwargs={'pk':self.object.pk})
```

and my url definition for that is:

```
url(r'^project/(?P<pk>\d+)$', ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='workspace_project'),
```

which is included in the main urlconf like this:

```
url('^workspace/', include('workspace.urls')),
```

however, whenever a create is successful, I receive this redirection error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /workspace/workspace/3/create_project

Reverse for '/workspace/project/12' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

I visited the url `/workspace/project/12` and I can access it. Why does this err anyway?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reason why you are using reverse() twice? Both in your get_success_url() and in your HttpResponseRedirect(). You also might want to references self.object.get_success_url().